# Get "mailfail" error even if form send a sucsess

Tags: php

I keep on getting my error message "Sorry your message could not be send" even if the forms sends and I receive the e mail with all the fields. It also doesn't go to the thank you page. Here is the code I think is needed.

So I placed a "var_dump" after my error message and I get "Boolean False" message. So if someone can please tell me what is causing this error and how to maybe to work around it? I was even thinking of changing my error message to a thank you message LOL.

```
<?php
$errors = array();
$missing = array();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "Carel Venter <bookings@bushveldgolf.co.za>";
    $subject = "Booking";
    $expected = array  ('b_name', 'b_surn', 'b_tele', 'b_mail', 'b_acco', 'b_golf', 'b_nong', 'b_pack', 'b_courses', 'b_dfrom', 'b_dto');
    $required = array('b_name', 'b_surn', 'b_tele', 'b_mail', 'b_acco', 'b_golf', 'b_pack', 'b_courses', 'b_dfrom', 'b_dto');
    if (!isset($_POST['b_courses'])) {
        $_POST['b_courses'] = array();
    }
    if(!is_array($_POST['b_courses'])) 
        {
            $_POST['b_courses'] = array($_POST['b_courses']);
        }
    $minimumChecked = 1;
    if (count($_POST['b_courses']) < $minimumChecked) {
        $errors['b_courses'] = true;}
    $headers = "From:" .$b_mail. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $authenticate = '-fcarel@bushveldgolf.co.za';
    require './php_include/mail_process2.php';
    if($mailsent) {
        header('Location:/thanks.php');
        exit;
    }
```

and here is the top of the form:

```
<?php if (($_POST && $suspect) || ($_POST && isset($errors['mailfail']))) { ?>
<p class="warning">Sorry your message could not be sent.</p>
     <?php } elseif ($errors || $missing) { ?>
<p class="warning">Please fix the item(s) indicated.</p>
     <?php }?>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
      <td width="25%">Name:</td>
      <td width="75%"><label>
      <input name="b_name" type="text" id="b_name" tabindex="1" size="30" maxlength="30"
      <?php 
      if ($errors || $missing) {
          echo 'value="' . htmlentities($b_name, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') . '"';
      }
?>
/>        
      <?php if ($missing && in_array('b_name', $missing)) { ?>
<span class="warning">Your name?</span>
     <?php } ?>
```

and my mail process script

```
<?php
  $suspect = false;
    $pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

    function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {
if  (is_array($val)) {
    foreach ($val as $item) {
        isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
    }
} else {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
        $suspect = true;
    }
}
    }
   isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);
    if (is_array($val)) {
        foreach ($val as $item) {
        isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
        }
    } else {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
            $suspect = true;
        }
    }

   isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);

   if (!$suspect) {
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
    $missing[] = $key;
    $$key = ''; 
} elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {
    $$key = $temp;
}
}
    }
   if (!$suspect && !empty($b_mail)) {
$validemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'b_mail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($validemail) {
$headers .= "\r\nReply-to: $validemail";
} else  {
    $errors['b_mail'] = true;
}

   }
   if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {
$message = '';
foreach ($expected as $item) {
    if (isset($$item) && !empty($$item)) {
        $val = $$item;
    } else {
        $val = 'Not selected';
    }
if (is_array($val)) {
    $val = implode(', ', $val);
}
$item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);
$message .= ucfirst($item) . ": $val\r\n\r\n";
}
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

$mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $authenticate);
if (!$mailsent) {
    $errors['mailfail'] = true;
}
  }
?>
```

Is there maybe any code I could place after the error message to show what is causing the "mailfail" to be executed?

Comment: What is $suspect varieble?

Comment: I included my whole mail process script now.

Comment: Before <?php if (($_POST && $suspect)... make var_dump($suspect);

Comment: I get "boolean false". What does that mean?